# Shortcut key/mouse to set specific shape key to 0?

Tags: shortcut, shape-keys

Is there a way to click a shape key and set it to zero? Like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> or something I think I did it by mistake one time, but can't figure out how.

I can't click and drag the number, since I have negative minimum range.

Now I need to click, type [0], and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It would be great to set it to 0 with one action, either keyboard and/or mouse.

It's the same action as "Reset to default value" which I can reach by right click and click in the menu. Maybe there is a way to bind that?

Thanks!

Comment: Hover the value slider with the mouse cursor and press `Backspace` to reset to zero

Comment: Great thanks! This should be an answer?:)